# Does somebody know what the tracking method in people_tracking_filter is?

Tags: ros, laser, tracking, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all. I am learning this [people package](http://wiki.ros.org/people?distro=indigo) by tracking legs. However, because there are no comments in the source code, I am confused about what kind of tracking method this package uses.

Is it a two-level tracking method? The low-level is by kalman filter, and the high-level is by particle filter. Each particle from particle filter is updated by kalman filter, i.e. a joint probablilistic data association filter(JPDAF)?

Thanks! @David lu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200261/does-somebody-know-what-the-tracking-method-in-people_tracking_filter-is?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The approach is in fact two levels. The "machine-learning" part outputs its best estimates for each time slice of where the legs are, and a kalman filter takes the successive readings and determines a smoothed estimate over time where the legs are.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2015-01-03**:
Thank you！ I know that the "machine-learning" part is used for detecting the legs. The kalman fitler is used for tracking the detected legs, right？
However，  I think maybe JPDAF is a better method for tracking people for a mobile robot.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-05**:
That's entirely possible.